# PhotoLibrary not open

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Image Gallery not open . Camera working fine but image getting from Photo Library Not getting they show blank screen. Yesterday it working Fine But today it not open . Please help any help would be apprciated. I am newer in Ios

```
 @IBAction func uploadImageClick (sender : UIButton){
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Gallery", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            self.presentViewController(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })


        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        })
        optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)

        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 extension NewsViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    func imagePickerController(
        picker: UIImagePickerController,
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your app have permission to access the photo library? You need to check permission (for the camera or the photo library as needed) before creating and presenting the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Have you added NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription into plist file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below thing in plist

> Key   is   Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
>
> Type  is  String
>
> Value  is uses Photos(Whatever you want give here)

[image: .plist image]